# c# - Linq 2 XML - how to read elements with the same names

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

the stucture of xml is:

```
<Rules>
    <rule ID="1" Parameter="IsD">
      <body>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Ratio>=</Ratio>
        <Value>no</Value>
        <Operation>AND</Operation>
        <ID>3</IF_ID>
        <Ratio>=</Ratio>
        <Value>yes</Value>
      </body>
      <value>no problems</value>
    </rule>
</Rules>
```

How can I read elements and create a rule with the following structure:

```
If (<ID><Ratio><Value><Operation><ID><Ratio><Value>)
```

ID is a question ID. In my case:

```
If (2 == no && 3 == yes)
```

Please, help me.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "create a rule with the following structure". Do you mean you're trying to *evaluate* that rule at execution time? Or store it in an object?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I think he wants to use the `xml` as a config file to set up some runtime logic. His problem seems to be, that certain element names are not unique (`ID`, `Ratio`)...

Comment: @froeschli: Possibly, yes... but more details would be helpful. It would be quite possible to answer this question in a reasonable way which turned out not to be helpful :(

Comment: @user647757 - Seems your `xml` has an error: should be `<ID>3</ID>` not `<ID>3</IF_ID>`...

Comment: @Jon Skee, yes I'm trying to evaluate this rule. I have a lot of rules, analyzing that I get one attribute from several parameters.

Comment: @user647757: In that case you need to explain what it means to compare "3" and "yes" for example...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: "3" means question's ID, and "yes" - answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Elements` method of the `XElement` class. For instance (supposing that you loop over all `rule`s) you could write

```
foreach (var rule in document.Root.Descendants("rule")) {
  var body = rule.Element("body");
  for (var i=0; i<body.Elements("ID").Count) {
    var id = body.Elemets("ID").ElementAt(i);
    var ratio = body.Elements("Ratio").ElementAt(i);
    var value = body.Elements("Value").ElementAt(i);
    /// ...
  }
}
```

Notet that accessing the elements of the `Elements` enumeration by use of `ElementAt()` might not be very efficient, another approach would be to iterate over the different subelements with separate `foreach` loops and store them in a `List` (or better, use the `ToList` Extension method).

The point is, that the `Elements` enumeration returns the subelements in *document order* i.e. in the same order as they appear in the input document (which is, what you need here).

A better solution would be (IMO) to put more structure in your input document in order to reflect the logic, like:

```
<Rules>
  <rule ID="1" Parameter="IsD">
    <body>
      <term >
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Ratio>=</Ratio>
        <Value>no</Value>
      </term>
      <term operation="and">
        <ID>3</IF_ID>
        <Ratio>=</Ratio>
        <Value>yes</Value>
      </term>
  </body>
  <value>no problems</value>
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick reply, now I will try